# Assembly 8086 homework - fill in the blank, misunderstanding

Tags: assembly, stack, x86-16

Firstly I'd like to apologize, english is not my native tongue and I couldn't come up with a title that better fits my situation.

I was given this incomplete assembly code:

```
.code
    mov [mybyte],______
    mov SP,0574h
    xor ax,ax
here:
    add AL,[mybyte]
    push AX
    dec BYTE PTR [mybyte]
    jnz here
    pop es
    nop
```

The question is: What should be written where _____ is, such that when we reach the "nop" command, the value of SP will be 570.

I understand the question, and I think I understand the code as well, but the problem is, the way i see it- SP never changes. The only place in the code where SP is referred to is at the line `mov sp,0574h`. So no matter what we write where ____ is, SP will not change.

Am I correct? Or did I misunderstand the code?

Comment: SP is the stack pointer, so it decrements at `push AX` (the stack grows downward in memory).

Comment: Ah, the push / pop commands change SP? Alright, this makes more sense then. Thank you. If you write it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: You can go ahead and accept Jester's answer, which covers the same ground more thoroughly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`push` changes `SP`, namely it decrements by `2`. `pop` also changes it, it does the opposite, it adds `2`. This is assuming 16 bit mode.

Since the final `pop` adds a `2` back, you need to loop 3 times to get `570h` from `574h`. Thus the correct value is `3`.

```
push AX ; SP = 572h
...
push AX ; SP = 570h
...
push AX ; SP = 56Eh
...
pop es  ; SP = 570h
```

Comment: I wish you wouldn't have told me the correct value is three, but after the clear explanation im sure i would have gotten that on my own. Thumbs up!

Comment: I have another question if that's okay. I ran the code where I put "3" instead of the line, and the answer is correct, SP is 570, but ES is not what i expect it to be. first time we push, we push 0003h. then we push 0002h, then we push 0001h, and then we pop. So I expected ES to be 0001h. But instead I see that ES is 0006h. Why is that?

Comment: You missed the `add AL`. It's not the byte that gets pushed, it's the sum. So `3+2+1=6`.

Answer (score 0):

Sry. Cant use comment yet. To answer your second question:
ES 0006 is correct. mybyte is decreased from 3 to 0 is right as well.  The only thing you are wrong with at the moment,  is what values are pushed to the stack. Just check again what happens to AL every loop cycle.

Spoiler:

Do not read if you want to find out yourself:

Mybyte is not moved into AL but added to it:
0 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 6